# How does the @Transient annotation get its value?

Tags: java, persistence, transient

So I understand that the `@Transient` from `javax.persistence.Transient` marks that a property or field is not persistent. But how does this property or field know what data it should be populated with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transient` means the field is not persisted, which also means it will not be fetched from the database. Its value is set by user code (e.g. a setter method).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. The field has its default value (null, for an object type) until some code initializes to something else.